# Using Visual Basic Type Characters on Variables

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory

Good afternoon everyone,

I have a simple problem I believe some of you will be able to solve or work around.  I am developing a program that will allow the user to select a process from a list of active processes, then edit it's memory values.

I am taking values, like the memory address and the new value, from text fields and parsing them to integers.  I then need to use these values in a function, where values, (specifically the address and offsets), are normally hard-coded with the `&H` type character.

Example, the address parameter would be specified like this: `&H00509B74`.
This type character does not work on variables, or functions, as the following examples are invalid syntax:
`&HAddress` or `&HInteger.Parse(AddressField.Text)`

How can I make it work or get around this?  Below is some of the code I am using.  I went back multiple times to edit this to make sure I left nothing out, please let me know if you need more information.
Thank you in advance for the help and time!

***Note: The write memory function is not mine, I found it on the web.***

***Note 2:  "ac_client" is the process name I am testing this on, and it is hard-coded because I have not implemented the process selector yet.***

Write Memory Function:

```
 Public Function WriteDMAInteger(ByVal Process As String, ByVal Address As Integer, ByVal Offsets As Integer(), ByVal Value As Integer, ByVal Level As Integer, Optional ByVal nsize As Integer = 4) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim lvl As Integer = Address
        For i As Integer = 1 To Level
            lvl = ReadInteger(Process, lvl, nsize) + Offsets(i - 1)
        Next
        WriteInteger(Process, lvl, Value, nsize)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Initializing Variables:

```
Process = "ac_client"
Address = Integer.Parse(AddressField.Text)
WriteValue = Integer.Parse(ValueField.Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
AddressField.Text = "00509B74"
```

then you can do

```
Address = Convert.ToInt32(AddressField.Text,16) 'this will convert an string containing a number written "in base 16", into an integer, and store it in the Address variable
```

If

```
AddressField.Text = "&H00509B74"
```

then you can simply ignore the fistr 2 character "&H" that are the VB specific Hex notation

```
Address = Convert.ToInt32(AddressField.Text.Substring(1,AddressField.Text.Length-2),16)
```

Comment: You sir, just made my day.  I've been looking all over for this!  I can finally get back to development now.  Thank you very much!